# angular4 multiple file upload second set files cleared

Tags: angular

I am new to angular

I am using multiple file upload

```
      <input #fileInput type="file"  multiple="true" ngModel class="form-control" name="image[]" accept="image/png, image/jpeg, image/gif" id="image" 
  (click)="fileInput.value = null;" (change)="onChange($event)">
```

### To display image preview I used below code

```
<div *ngFor="let item of filelist; let i = index; " >
            <img  *ngIf="item != '' " id='img-upload' [src]="item"> 
 </div>
```

### Image onchhange evnet

I declared `tmp_files :File[] = [] ;` as like this

```
   onChange(event:any) {   


  //this.fupload = event.srcElement.files;  // not working in firefox
  this.fupload = event.target.files; 
// to get the files in array

  this.tmp_files.push(event.target.files);

  //console.log(event.target.files.length+' <> '+this.dind.length);
  this.urlval = event.target.files[0].name;




  for(let i=0; i< event.target.files.length; i++ ) {

    if (event.target.files && event.target.files[i]) {
      var reader = new FileReader();
      reader.onload = (event:any) => {
        this.url = event.target.result;
        this.filelist.push(this.url);

      }
      reader.readAsDataURL(event.target.files[i]);
    }
  }
```

}

I  choose 3 files

[image: Image display like this]
[image: Console log for this.tmp_files variable]

### Again I select 2 files

[image]

### The console log as:

[image]

Here in the tmp_files variable the Fileset 0 is cleared and in array the last selected two files only available.

I dont know this is why.  (Fileset 0 - length as 0. fileset 1 length as 2). But in preview I have 5 fiels. Please help me

Answer (score 0):

1) The reason you get only 2 files in second time is that the file control resets its collection the moment you do a selection again. If you want multiple files, you need to select them at a single go. Else take files and add them to your local collection and again add (you are right now doing this correctly)

2) The reason you are seeing 5 files in the preview, is that everytime you have selected the files, you are adding their details in your local collection "this.filelist". This collection is preserved across file selection (require manual reset).

You are doing work correctly, just take the files added in your local collection and do the processing with it. No problems anywhere in your code (till now)